# Ui-Select - adding an static directive as footer

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, autocomplete, ui-select

I'm working now over Ui-Select.

Now my task is put an static button or text with a link as a footer inside the ui-select, that will show how much coincidence exists with the text written.

I'm having problems to make my footer directive show just when there is more than 4 elements on the ng-repeat.

If you see on my **[plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/aYIDBmShGqPMp422OBIK/preview)**; I just put my footer behind the ui-select, but it must be inside, just when ui-select-choices **open** and the results with the text written are more than 4.

***Can any body help me?***

***Thanks***

*The source code is on this* [***link***](https://mega.nz/#!pkIE2RpT!_cI8VgzN-Xf58xgKweOTA2OJf2vFZNFcZ1efMrOoBH8)

Answer (score 0):

There's this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/pull/496
Doesn't look like it is merged to the release yet though.